# 1-D diffusion differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One-dimensional neutron diffusion equation described by $$-D \frac{d^2 \phi}{dx^2} + DC^2 \phi=0$$ 
How may I determine the solution to this differential equation? I substituted a trial function as $\phi =e^{ikx}$ from where I arrived to a general solution.$$\phi =Ae^{Cx}+Be^{-Cx}$$ Not sure how to determine the co-efficients of each of the terms in the general solution and thereby the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: To determine the coefficients, plug in your boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your general solution seems fine. However, you will need two initial conditions, specified in your problem, (eg: $\phi(0) = 0$  and $\phi ' (0) = 1$) in order to determine the constants $A$ and $B$ and have a specific solution to the problem. Without any initial conditions, the general solution is the best you can do.

Once you have the initial conditions, plugging them into your general solution gives two equations and two unknowns allowing you to solve for $A$ and $B$. For example, if $\phi(0) = 0$  and $\phi ' (0) = 1$, then, $$\phi (0) = A + B = 0$$ and $$\phi ' (0) = cA - cB = 1$$ Now you can solve for $A$ and $B$.